# Bounded linear operator with non-dense range

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A:X\rightarrow Y$ be a bounded linear operator between Banach spaces. Suppose $\overline{R(A)}\neq Y$. How to prove that there exist $y^*\in Y^*$ s.th. for any $x\in X $ we have $\langle y^*, Ax \rangle=0$ ? (where $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ means dual pairing). I think I should use Hahn-Banach theorem, but now I don't see how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean something like $y^* \circ A = 0$?

The Hahn-Banach theorem lets you extend (continuous) linear functionals defined on closed subspaces of $Y$ to (continuous) functionals defined on all of $Y$. In this case, take the zero functional on $\overline{(R(A)}$ and extend it to a functional $y^*$ on $Y$.

I think you also want to ensure that $y^* \not = 0$ identically on $Y$. You can do this using the idea above (it is easy to extend functionas from a finite codimension subspace $V$ of a Banach space $W$ to a functional on $W$ ... does this hint make sense to you?)

Edit:

More detail:

Prove the following lemma:

If $X$ is a closed subspace of finite codimension of a Banach space $Y$, then there is a functional which is zero on $X$ and nonzero on $Y$. For this, you can use the quotient map $Y / X \cong R^n$. (Actually once it is finite codimension I think it it is automatically closed.)

So take some vector not in $\overline{R(A)}$ and prove that the space spanned by $\overline{R(A)}$ and $v$ is still closed. $\overline{R(A)}$ is finite codimension here, so by the previous lemma you can find a functional which vanishes on $\overline{R(A)}$ but not on $Span (v, \overline{R(A)})$. Now extend this function to $Y$ using Hahn-Banach.

Comment: I don't see how to construct such a functional. We can take some $y\in Y\setminus \overline{R(A)}$ and define $g(y)=1$ and $g=0$ on $\overline{R(A)}$. My idea is now using Hahn-Banach theorem for $g$ to obtain $y^*$, but why $g$ is continuous ?

Comment: @mikis I updated my answer.

Comment: @mikis Specifically, it is continuous because of finite codimension, as I outlined in my answer.

Comment: Why $\overline{R(A)}$ has finite codimension? It is the only part of this proof, which I don't see.

Comment: The point is that the span of $v$ and $\overline(R(A))$ is still closed. For instance, this is because this span is the preimage of the span of $v$ in $X/ \overline(R(A))$. So $\overline(R(A))$ in $Span(\overline(R(A)), v)$ is codimension one. The lemma that I was using repeatedly throughout this is that the quotient map obtained by modding out by a closed subspace is a continuous map onto another Banach space. The proof is: once you know that $X / \overline{(R(A)}$ is a Banach space, build a nonzero functional on the quotient using Hahn-Banach, then pull it back to X.